# setup_requires with Cython?

Tags: python, build, cython, setuptools, software-distribution

I'm creating a `setup.py` file for a project with some Cython extension modules.

I've already gotten this to work:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name=...,
    ...,
    ext_modules=cythonize([ ... ]),
)
```

This installs fine. However, this assumes Cython is installed. What if it's not installed? I understand this is what the `setup_requires` parameter is for:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name=...,
    ...,
    setup_requires=['Cython'],
    ...,
    ext_modules=cythonize([ ... ]),
)
```

However, if Cython isn't already installed, this will of course fail:

```
$ python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ImportError: No module named Cython.Build
```

What's the proper way to do this? I need to somehow import `Cython` only after the `setup_requires` step runs, but I need `Cython` in order to specify the `ext_modules` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must wrap the `from Cython.Build import cythonize` in a `try-except`, and in the `except`, define `cythonize` as a dummy function. This way the script can be loaded without failing with an `ImportError`.

Then later when the `setup_requires` argument is handled, `Cython` will be installed and the setup script will be re-executed. Since at that point `Cython` is installed, you'll be able to successfully import `cythonize`

```
try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
except ImportError:
     def cythonize(*args, **kwargs):
         from Cython.Build import cythonize
         return cythonize(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT

As noted in comments, after setuptools deals with missing dependencies, it won't re-load Cython. I hadn't thought of it before, but you could also try a late-binding approach to stubbing out `cythonize`

Comment: That's somewhat hacky, and yet, pretty cool! Didn't know the script is re-executed, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hmm, so if I install without Cython having been installed first, the setup works (it installs Cython) but the extension modules aren't installed (can't import them from scripts). Any ideas of what may be happening?

Comment: Curious. Ah well it must not be truly re-executed. I usually don't require `Cython` for installation, just development. Instead of making `Extension` instances with `cythonize`, just create them directly on the `Cython` generated .c files. Checkout this example https://github.com/mobiusklein/brainpy/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: I should clarify that in that case you'll also need to make sure to include .h, .pyx, pxd, and .c files in the MANIFEST file for your distribution.

Comment: Oh hmm, that's not a bad idea. I'll keep that floating around in the ol' noggin for a bit.

Comment: How is one supposed to pass `gdb_debug=True` to `cythonize` if the function is not used?

Answer (score 33):

Starting from [18.0](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#180) release of `setuptools` (released on 2015-06-23) it is possible to specify `Cython` in `setup_requires` and pass `*.pyx` modules sources for regular `setuptools.Extension`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    # ...
    setup_requires=[
        # Setuptools 18.0 properly handles Cython extensions.
        'setuptools>=18.0',
        'cython',
    ],
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            'mylib',
            sources=['src/mylib.pyx'],
        ),
    ],
)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Would you prefer this approach next to the approach were Cython files are compiled in advance and .c files are used in setup.py, which means that Cython is not needed to build the package?

Comment: @Martinsos assuming that Cython is installable on all target platforms using setuptools (it should, but there are always exceptions), using specified approach removes hassle of generating those .c files during library deployment without loosing anything, so yes, I would recommend this approach. The only exception if this process doesn't work, e.g. if you target system with very old setuptools, which I wouldn't by default.

Comment: Are you sure it works? I tried with Python 3.5, setuptools 39.0.1. If cython is not installed, it gives error: unknown file type '.pyx'

Comment: @Labo I assume you opened this bug report for mentioned issue? https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1317

Comment: @rutsky indeed ;)

Comment: This is very useful. In this setup, without importing cython, do you know how we could set cython compiler options, as we would do with:
```
from Cython.Compiler import Options

Options.annotate = True
```

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a third way of having build dependencies installed before executing the actual `setup.py` described here (requires `pip`):

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#basic-setup-

In essence:

1. Create the file `pyproject.toml` with the following contents:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

2. Use `pip install -e .` for setting things up