# How should I handle importing third-party libraries within my setup.py script?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm developing a Python application and in the process of branching off a release. I've got a PyPI server set up on a company server and I've copied a source distribution of my package onto it.

I checked that the package was being hosted on the server and then tried installing it on my local development machine. I ended up with this output:

```
$ pip3 install --trusted-host 172.16.1.92 -i http://172.16.1.92:5001/simple/ <my-package>
Collecting <my-package>
  Downloading http://172.16.1.92:5001/packages/<my-package>-0.2.0.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ubb3jkpr\<my-package>\setup.py", line 9, in <module>
        import appdirs
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appdirs'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ubb3jkpr\<my-package>\
```

The reason is that I'm trying to import a third-party library `appdirs` in my `setup.py`, which is necessary for me to compute the `data_files` argument to `setup()`:

```py
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

import os
from collections import defaultdict

import appdirs
from <my-package>.version import __version__ as <my-package>_version

APP_NAME = '<my-app>'
APP_AUTHOR = '<company>'
SYSTEM_COMPONENT_PLUGIN_DIR = os.path.join(appdirs.user_data_dir(APP_NAME, APP_AUTHOR), 'components')

# ...

setup(
    # ...
    data_files=component_files,
)
```

However, I don't have `appdirs` installed on my local dev machine and I don't expect the end users to have it either.

Is it acceptable to rely on third-party libraries like this in `setup.py`, and if so what is the recommended approach to using them? Is there a way I can ensure `appdirs` gets installed before it's imported in `setup.py`, or should I just document that `appdirs` is a required package to install my package?

Comment: Have you tried using `setup_requires`?  See https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.4.1/cookbook.html#controlling-setup-requires

Comment: @PeterBrittain Are there any examples of how to use it? Should I do something like make two `setup()` calls, one near the top of `setup.py` with just `setup_requires=['appdirs']` and the one I have already at the bottom?

Comment: It's not common... You can find a simple example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471313/setup-requires-with-cython.  That begins to show the sorts of hoops mentioned in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/ which highlights another option for doing this with pip that should be available soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm ignoring licensing issues in this answer. You definetly need to take these into account before you really do a release.

> Is it acceptable to rely on third-party libraries like this in setup.py

Yes, it is acceptable but generally these should be minimized, especially if these are modules which have no obvious use for the end-user. Noone likes to have packages they don't need or use.

> what is the recommended approach to using them?

There are basically 3 options:

- Bootstrap them (for example use `pip` to programmatically install packages). For example [`setuptools` provides an `ez_setup.py` file](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#building-and-distributing-packages-with-setuptools) that can be used to bootstrap `setuptools`. Maybe that can be customized to download and install `appdirs`.
- Include them (especially if it's a small package) in your project. For example `appdirs` is basically just a single file module. Pretty easy to copy and maintain in your project. Be very careful with licensing issues when you do that!
- Fail gracefully when it's not possible to import them and let the user install them. For example:

  ```
  try:
      import appdirs
  except ImportError:
      raise ImportError('this package requires "appdirs" to be installed. '
                        'Install it first: "pip install appdirs".')
  ```

Comment: Looks like `appdirs` is licensed under MIT, so of the three the second option seems most appealing. Ideally `setup_requires` (which @PeterBrittain recommends) looks like the best solution, but I'm not exactly sure how to use it.

Comment: Well, it depends on the license, the size, the stability and if you also need it as runtime-dependency to decide which approach is the "most appealing". I personally don't like `setup_requires` because it's annoying (impossible) to use with some ways of locally installing a package (I think `python setup.py install`, `python setup.py develop` or `pip install .` won't work).

Comment: `appdirs` seems to resolve paths weirdly when run as a local module, so I went with the third option.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `pip` to install the package programmatically if the `import` fails:

```
try:
    import appdirs
except ImportError:
    import pip
    pip.main(['install', 'appdirs'])
    import appdirs
```

In some circumstances you may need to use `importlib` or `__import__` to import the package after `pip.main` or referesh the `PATH` variable. It could also be worthwhile to include a verification if the user really wants to install that package before installing it.

I used a lot of the examples from ["Installing python module within code"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12332975/5393381) and I haven't personally tried used this in `setup.py` files but it looks like it could be a solution for your question.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. This seems like a painless and functional solution to the problem that I personally was having.

Answer (score 1):

You can mention install_requires with the dependencies list. Please check the python packaging guide [here](https://packaging.python.org/requirements/). Also you can provide a requirements.txt file so that it can be run at once using "pip install -r"

Comment: I'm not sure how `install_requires` would help, did you mean [`setup_requires`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords)? However in my experience it's tricky to get right. Especially if one can't garantuee that `setuptools` is installed and given the `try: from setuptools import setup` that's not garantueed.

Comment: If am not wrong, setup_requires just downloads the dependencies but install_requires installs them, I agree setup tools should be imported.

Comment: @Venu: it is fine to require `setuptools` to be able to install your package. If you use `pip` to install, `setuptools` is bundled already. I'd just use `setuptools` and `setup_requires` here.