# setup.py: add dependencies required for installation

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, pybind11

For distributing Python libraries on PyPi, I usually specify the package's dependencies in `setup.py` à la

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=["numpy", "scipy"],
    # ...
)
```

In some cases, however, I already need to import something in the `setup.py`, for example when using pybind11. The [recommended way](https://github.com/pybind/python_example/blob/master/setup.py) for finding the pybind11 include directory is via

```
def __str__(self):
    import pybind11  # !
    return pybind11.get_include(self.user)
```

Hence, the user needs `pybind11` installed *before* pip tries to install the library itself. Unfortunately, simply adding the module to `install_requires` doesn't cut it: One gets

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'
```

when trying to install. Is there a way to enforce installation of requirements before evaluating `setup.py`?

Comment: I think that the dependencies are installed quite early on. So did you try to simply add pybind11 to the required list? If it is evaluated before finding your include path it might just work like that

Comment: If you mean `install_requires` by "required list" then yes, I did try that. Not working.(I'll clarify that in the question.)

Comment: Take a look at this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308548/how-should-i-handle-importing-third-party-libraries-within-my-setup-py-script)