# setup.py: Depend on CSS and JS packages

Tags: javascript, python, dependencies, setup.py

I have [a Python project](https://github.com/nschloe/tuna) which displays some information in the browser and uses [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [D3](https://d3js.org/) to do so. Right now, I'm simply including `bootstrap.min.css` and `d3.v5.min.js` in the source code repository, add them to the `package_data` in `setup.py`, and update them as new versions are released. This is rather ugly of course.

I'd like to specify bootstrap and D3 as a dependency in `setup.py`; any hint on how this could be possible?

Comment: may be using data files ? https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files

Comment: @Sreyas Well, the files are of course specified in `setup.py` _somehow_ so they get installed at all; in my case as `package_data`. I still need to keep them in the repo though. Clarified in the question.

Comment: Do you mean you want the files be downloaded while installing this package? Actually I don't this is a good idea as in this case this package won't be able to installed offline. Maybe a better choice is add some code in your `setup.py` to automatically download these files while packaging. So that the built wheel contains everything you need and files get update automatically when you release a new version.

Comment: Well, if you install something you need to be online anyways, right? I'm never packaging all of my Python dependencies either.

Comment: If you expect your users to be online to begin with, you could point to a CDN instead.  If for some reason you don't want to serve those libraries through a CDN, you will need to require some kind of front-end dependency management package on the target system.  If you can assume that, then you can override `build` or `build_ext` (or some other fitting build step that pip goes through) class in the `cmdclass` argument to `setup` to install these front-end deps via yarn/npm/whatever.

Comment: How about detecting and downloading files manually in `setup.py`? Those code will be executed while installing.

Comment: @Sraw Yes, it'll have to be something like that. One problem (perhaps not related to this question exactly) is that I'll require `requests` at installation time, but there's no way to specify them yet (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323748/setup-py-add-dependencies-required-for-installation)).

Comment: `requests` is one of the dependencies of `pip`. So if user use `pip install ...` to install your package, it should have `requests`.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/master/src/pip/_vendor/requests