# No module named 'Cython' with pip installation of tar.gz

Tags: python, cython, pipenv, python-poetry

I use Poetry to build  tar.gz and whl files for my example package (https://github.com/iamishalkin/cyrtd) and then try to install package inside pipenv environment. tar.gz installation fails and this is a piece of logs:

```
$ poetry build
...
$ pip install dist/cyrtd-0.1.0.tar.gz
Processing c:\work2\cyrtd\dist\cyrtd-0.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython<0.30.0,>=0.29.13 in c:\users\ivan.mishalkin\.virtualenvs\cyrtd-tpdvsw8x\lib\site-packages (from cyrtd==0.1.0) (0.29.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: cyrtd
  Building wheel for cyrtd (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
from Cython.Build import cythonize
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'  
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dxpyfeed
Failed to build dxpyfeed
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dxpyfeed which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Cython is installed and is callable from virtual interpreter. Even in logs it is written, that requirements for cython are satisfied.
What is strange - everything worked fine couple months ago. I also tried conda venv, upgraded cython and poetry, nothing helped. 
Also tried weakly related workaround from [setup_requires with Cython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471313/setup-requires-with-cython) - still no luck

**UPD**: I found some dirty workaround here: https://luminousmen.com/post/resolve-cython-and-numpy-dependencies

The idea is to add

```
from setuptools import dist
dist.Distribution().fetch_build_eggs(['cython'])
```

before Cython.Build import

After this I get these logs:

```
$ pip install dist/cyrtd-0.1.0.tar.gz
Processing c:\work2\cyrtd\dist\cyrtd-0.1.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython<0.30.0,>=0.29.13 in c:\users\ivan.mishalkin\.virtualenvs\cyrtd-tpdvsw8x\lib\site-packages (from cyrtd==0.1.0) (0.29.15)
Building wheels for collected packages: cyrtd
  Building wheel for cyrtd (PEP 517) ... done
  Created wheel for cyrtd: filename=cyrtd-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl size=33062 sha256=370a90657759d3183f3c11ebbdf1d23c3ca857d41dd45a86386ba33a6baf9a07
  Stored in directory: c:\users\ivan.mishalkin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\45\d1\6b\52daecf1cc5234ca4d9e9e49b2f195e7adb83941424116432e
Successfully built cyrtd
Installing collected packages: cyrtd
  Attempting uninstall: cyrtd
    Found existing installation: cyrtd 0.1.0
    Uninstalling cyrtd-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled cyrtd-0.1.0
Successfully installed cyrtd-0.1.0
```

Still looking for a better solution

**UPD2:**
main files content:
build.py:

```
from setuptools import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

cyfuncs_ext = Extension(name='cyrtd.cymod.cyfuncs',
                        sources=['cyrtd/cymod/cyfuncs.pyx']
                        )

EXTENSIONS = [
    cyfuncs_ext
]

def build(setup_kwargs):
    setup_kwargs.update({
        'ext_modules': cythonize(EXTENSIONS, language_level=3),
        'zip_safe': False,
        'setup_requires':['setuptools>=18.0', 'cython']
    })
```

Comment: is the `build.py` script set as the value in `[tool.poetry].build`, or how do you bind it?

Comment: @Arne yes, of course it is binded in `pyproject.toml` file. The repo from question contains all the code

Comment: ah, I didn't see that you linked your repo. is this a proper solution for you, or are you still looking for something better? If it's good enough, consider posting it as a self-contained answer.

Comment: @Arne some time ago everything worked fine without such workaround, so I am confident that there is better solution. The problem is that I do not know, what have changed and where to search for bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding cython in build-system section in `pyproject.toml` helped me

`pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12", "cython"]
...
```

Comment: To my surprise this fixed it for me too